# Positioning info icons on top of other images

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to achieve the same as this guy here: [css positioning of an info-note on the top of an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146144/css-positioning-of-an-info-note-on-the-top-of-an-icon)

But in my case I have the info icons on top of other images, see this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/usuyu3/5

I'd like to position the info icons in the lowerleft corners of the table headers, thus relatively in the same position.

When I use position:relative on the .tooltip class, the info icons show, but I can't get them on top of the tables.

When using position:absolute, I can get 1 icon on top of the tables, but the others become invisible.

How would I solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  a.tooltip .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.1em;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    color: black;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  a.tooltip {
    text-decoration: none;
      position: absolute;
    margin-top: -345px !important;
      margin-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 152px;
  }
  a.tooltip:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
  }
.overflow {
    margin:124px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height:213px;
    color: #8C8C8B;
    width: 100%;
}

.overflow p {
padding-top: 0px;
}

#onside { padding-top: 7px;} 
#logopakketten {position: relative; z-index: 1; margin-left: 158px; margin-top: -332px; overflow: visible;}     

.column {
display:block;
float:left;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="overflow">
<div id="onside">
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum:</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="logopakketten">
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/logopakketten/test.png" alt="" /> 
  <a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/infoicoontje.png" alt="" /><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 1</span></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/logopakketten/test.png" alt="" /> 
  <a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/infoicoontje.png" alt="" /><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 2</span></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/logopakketten/test.png" alt="" /> 
  <a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/infoicoontje.png" alt="" /><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 3</span></a>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/logopakketten/test.png" alt="" /> 
  <a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/images/infoicoontje.png" alt="" /><span class="tooltip">Tooltip 4</span></a>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use 'z-index' in css.

Higher z-index value of an element means that the element will appear above the others with lower z-index.
In css, make sure the elements that you want to appear have greater z-index than the rest. If you have not put the z-index, you can put them now.

Note: z-index depends on the existence of 'position' value in css. That means, without 'position', z-index is meaningless

I hope this helps

Comment: That won't work. Even if I use z-index I can't use my negative margin-top to position the info icons over the tables :(

Comment: I have seen your code source. It cannot be like that. Each column must be put in one div, with one tooltip included in each div.